Run `partman.create_parent` Idempotently
Problem Description
I'm using the Postgres extension pg_partman 5.1 to partition a set of tables inside of a number of initialization scripts. I'm using these scripts both to setup remote databases and as part of a local docker testing environment.
as part of this setup process I'm running partman.create_parent which I can successfully run once. But I'm not able to get this to run a second time due to a key constraint from an insert that's contained in the function that's called.
I would love to be able to run these setup scripts multiple times as developers make small tweaks to the system. I could always destroy and re-create the entire system from scratch in the docker environment but if I can re-run the init scripts and get no-ops if this has already been run once that would be excellent.
Another option would be checking to see if the public.all_observations key already exists and if so don't run the query but I'm not 100% sure to accomplish that.
Specific Statement
    SELECT partman.create_parent(
        p_parent_table :='public.all_observations',
        p_control :='ts',
        p_type :='range',
        p_interval :='1 day',
        p_start_partition :='2024-05-01',
        p_template_table :='public.all_observations_template');

Things I've Tried
DO $$ BEGIN
    SELECT partman.create_parent(
        p_parent_table :='public.all_observations',
        p_control :='ts',
        p_type :='range',
        p_interval :='1 day',
        p_start_partition :='2024-05-01',
        p_template_table :='public.all_observations_template');
EXCEPTION
       WHEN unique_violation THEN null;
END $$;

Error I'm Hitting
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexlordthorsen/git/iocurrents-services/configuration_management/helper_scripts/bootstrap_dbs.py", line 189, in <module>
    main()
  File "/Users/alexlordthorsen/git/iocurrents-services/configuration_management/helper_scripts/bootstrap_dbs.py", line 185, in main
    run_bootstrap_file(conn, file_path, env, template_args)
  File "/Users/alexlordthorsen/git/iocurrents-services/configuration_management/helper_scripts/bootstrap_dbs.py", line 147, in run_bootstrap_file
    cursor.execute(sql)
psycopg2.errors.RaiseException: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "part_config_parent_table_pkey"
CONTEXT: SQL statement "INSERT INTO partman.part_config (
        parent_table
        , partition_type
        , partition_interval
        , epoch
        , control
        , premake
        , constraint_cols
        , datetime_string
        , automatic_maintenance
        , jobmon
        , template_table
        , inherit_privileges
        , default_table
        , date_trunc_interval)
    VALUES (
        p_parent_table
        , p_type
        , v_time_interval
        , p_epoch
        , p_control
        , p_premake
        , p_constraint_cols
        , v_datetime_string
        , p_automatic_maintenance
        , p_jobmon
        , v_template_schema||'.'||v_template_tablename
        , v_inherit_privileges
        , p_default_table
        , p_date_trunc_interval)"
PL/pgSQL function partman.create_parent(text,text,text,text,text,integer,text,boolean,text,text[],text,boolean,text) line 345 at SQL statement
SQL statement "SELECT partman.create_parent(
        p_parent_table :='public.all_observations',
        p_control :='ts',
        p_type :='range',
        p_interval :='1 day',
        p_start_partition :='2024-05-01',
        p_template_table :='public.all_observations_template')"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at SQL statement
DETAIL: Key (parent_table)=(public.all_observations) already exists.
HINT:
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function partman.create_parent(text,text,text,text,text,integer,text,boolean,text,text[],text,boolean,text) line 647 at RAISE
SQL statement "SELECT partman.create_parent(
        p_parent_table :='public.all_observations',
        p_control :='ts',
        p_type :='range',
        p_interval :='1 day',
        p_start_partition :='2024-05-01',
        p_template_table :='public.all_observations_template')"
PL/pgSQL function inline_code_block line 2 at SQL statement


Surely you can query partman.part_config to see if parent_table is there -- the error messages gives you all the necessary information.
